# React Objects are not valid as a React child, wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons

Tags: reactjs, coffeescript, react-rails

I am trying to render a few properties to the element on the basis of a condition in react as follows:

```
dom.span
  className: "btn pull-right btn-primary#{if @state.enableCartButton then '' else ' disabled'}"
  if @state.enableCartButton
    onClick: @submitCustomizeForm
  else
    'data-toggle': "tooltip"
    'data-placement': "left"
    title: "Select a measurement profile to continue"
  translate('store.products.customize.save', 'ADD TO CART')
```

But getting the following errors depeding on the condition,

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child
>   (found: object with keys {onClick}). If you meant to render a
>   collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method
>   of `Constructor`.

OR

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child
>   (found: object with keys {data-toggle, data-placement, title}). If you
>   meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap
>   the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check
>   the render method of `Constructor`.

The following piece of code works though,

```
if @state.enableCartButton
  dom.span
    className: "btn pull-right btn-primary"
    onClick: @submitCustomizeForm
    translate('store.products.customize.save', 'ADD TO CART')
else
  dom.span
    className: "btn pull-right btn-primary disabled"
    'data-toggle': "tooltip"
    'data-placement': "top"
    title: "Select a measurement profile to continue."
    translate('store.products.customize.save', 'ADD TO CART')
```

Moreover, I am not sure why I am not able to render multiple elements inside an if/for in react. Only one element is allowed, if I render more than one than only the last one gets rendered in the HTML

Comment: Coffeescript doesn't have such a conditional key functionality. You could follow the advice at the bottom here https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3928 but just think what works in normal javascript (which doesn't have conditional keys in object literals)

Comment: Did you mean to say that there is currently no solution to this?

Comment: There is, of course a solution. You can define the props object, then conditionally add keys `props = {}; if (cond) props.key = value`. With regards to multiple components per condition, you can return an array of components instead of just one.

Comment: but i am rendering only one component (span), just that the properties/data-attributes are different on the basis of condition

Comment: So do what I just said above? Which part are you still confused about? or for that matter, the second block of code you posted.. what's wrong with that? you said it works...

Comment: second one works without any flaw. but ideally I would want the first one to work. So my question is, is it possible to make the first one work somehow?

Comment: yes by creating the props object first then conditionally adding keys. then you pass that to your span function.

Comment: but i have to use state and not props to determine if the keys should be rendered or not